# Why is my request working in postman but not axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to make a request in axios. The same request works in postman.

```
await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `https://ecommersappbytim.herokuapp.com/info/${userId}/update-user`,
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": { token },
      },
      data: {
        firstName: userInfo.fName,
        lastName: userInfo.lName,
        email: userInfo.email,
        password: userInfo.password,
      },
    })
```

Is there something I am missing? I have made sure that I am passing in the correct data.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work in axios"?

Comment: Request failed with status code 401, is the error message I receive.

Comment: Right, so the authentication fails, I guess? Why `"auth-token": { token },` as opposed to `"auth-token": token`?

Comment: That was for some reason the autocompletion, I have changed it since and still receive the same error.

Comment: Also, did you inspect the xhr in the browser's dev tools? Does it really look exactly as supposed to? If I make a [random request](https://jsfiddle.net/12nac86x/) I can reproduce this, and the error message is "cannot authorize token". Are you getting this, too?

Comment: I can't see the request header you made in postman? Did you debugger your code in try catch? It is difficult to solve the problem without returning any errors.